# Sharepoint Online Management Shell Functionality

Tags: powershell

I am trying to script the deployment of multiple site collections online. This will enable us to create site collections from powershell.

I have previously used the dll's (shown in the image) and then wrote powershell scripts which load the dll's and to create the following objects. This has been successful in the past.

- Site Collections
- Document Libraries
- Activate features
- Create Content Types

[image]

However I have been informed it is possible to use [Sharepoint Online Management Shell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35588#) to achieve the same functionality without loading the dll's. Does anyone have any examples that I can see?

Answer (score 0):

To create a site collection use this cmdlet: `New-SPOSite` described in detail [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161370.aspx).

Example usage from link:

```
New-SPOSite -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/accounting -Owner admin@contoso.com -StorageQuota 100 -NoWait -ResourceQuota 50 -Template STS#0
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. However is it possible to create Document Libraries
Activate features
Create Content Types

Comment: For those kinds of more advanced deployments I would keep using CSOM as you have done before, it is a much more complete API available than in the online management shell